# How do I make money quickly in Uplink?

Tags: uplink

What are some ways of making quick money, ( stealing from banks is too dangerous )
Can I make money using the stock market?

Comment: Haven't played in so long I've forgotten :) fun game.

Comment: Indeed it is. how come no one is answering :(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The quickest way to make money is to rob a bank.

Therefore, here's *How To Rob A Bank version 2.0*:

- Get to the Intermediate ranking
- Look for "**Trace A Balance Transfer**" missions.  **Accept** as many as you can.  As you complete them, note down the **bank IP** and **account numbers** of the accounts which received the money.  You won't get these missions after you increase in level, so make sure you accept as many as you can.
- Also, connect to Uplink International Bank and note down **their IP** and **your account number**. *Alternatively, create an account for yourself at the target bank. Note down the account number.*
- Set up a nice long bounce route.  Try to have administrator access on the systems you bounce through, it makes passive traces slower.  Use InterNIC as your first bounce.
- Connect to the bank and **bypass** or **disable** the security.  Bypass is preferred if you have that option.
- At the bank login screen, **enter the account number** of the target account, and **use the password cracker** to gain access.
- Once inside, **transfer** the contents of the account to your Uplink International Bank account, using the details you noted down earlier. *Alternatively, if you created an account at the target bank, transfer the money to that account instead.*
- Pull up the target's bank statement and use the Log Deleter to **remove the transfer statement** from the target account. *If you created an account at the target bank instead, delete the transfer statement showing an input from your account there as well.*
- Disconnect, and then **connect** to the Uplink International Bank using your saved bounce trail.  (you did save it, didn't you?)
- **Bypass** Uplink International Bank's security.  Log in to your account.
- **Delete the statement logs** indicating that your account received an input.
- **Connect** to InterNIC and **delete** the bounce logs.
- You'll know if you succeeded because you'll get

  > an immediate promotion to Uber-Skilled.
- Congratulations!  You're a bank robber!  You scoundrel.

Comment: This should be the best way to make money, but the timing has to be spot on. If you're not fast enough, you'll be disavowed before you even get to look at your bank balance.

Comment: @sykora's comment:  If you're having trouble with passive traces, you need a longer bounce trail, or you need to get administrator access on more of the systems in the trail.  There's unfortunately no way around this, but luckily, you only need to build the trail once.

Comment: Tip:  You only really need to do this once, if you find a big account.  (Around 1M credits.)  After that, it's not worth the risk because you will have more money than you'll ever need.

Comment: Just to point out that its much easier if you open a bank account at the target bank first. That way you can edit the logs of both accounts without needing to bypass Uplink Bank's security.

Comment: Good answer, I'd just like to add that if you are lazy or you are using your first computer and are going to upgrade the whole thing anyways, you can just nuke your computer through the gateway nuke program (or running the virus) to remove all traces back to yourself preemptively. (also it is good to find a file server before hand and copy all your programs over to save a few bucks)

Comment: @BiffMaGriff - if your bank robbery succeeds, the price of a new file copier / deleter will be negligible, to say the least.

Comment: @SteveV. It's weird because I do it in real life too. I'll pay a huge amount money for hardware but I don't want to spend any more money than I have to on software.

Comment: You can always see your own bank details on the '$' tab - you don't need to note them down.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since I played, so things might have changed since then, but back in the day there was a way to make the game ridiculously easy *(that some people may consider cheating, so **if you don't want to ruin the game, stop reading**)*.

> IIRC, there is a public IP directory you can access right from the start of the game (either it's in your list of starting IPs, or it's some constant address that doesn't change from game-to-game).  Accessing this at the start of the game will give you all the IPs you will ever need - simply route every hack-attempt through every IP listed there.
>
> I remember doing this on my second play-through, and getting very bored because you get 600+ seconds for every hack attempt, allowing you to hack even difficult targets with a low-powered PC.

Comment: Hmm... but I still would have to do a whole bunch of missions :(

Comment: @bronzebread:  Not if you hack a bank...

Comment: Personally I found it more bothersome for later advanced missions to go that route, as I would "add" the phone number of the system administrator right next to the internal services system, mainframe, and all other ip addresses for the company, as I didn't like to connect to the public server for the phone number each time.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most simple ways is to get a batch of copy/delete missions and check if any are on the same server.

The same can go for missions on government databases, if you make sure you're hard to trace and you're quick about it.

Comment: yup, I am already batching stuff, but still not as quick as stealing 200K straight up :D

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way by far I've found was to simply rob a bank.

1. open bank account at a random bank
2. hack a bank and find someone with loads of money
3. transfer money over to you
4. make sure to delete all access and trasaction logs at BOTH banks (this will require hacking both of them)

The details might be off but this is the way to earn loads of money pretty early (you do need some hardware and software for a hack though), which makes the game very easy later.

Comment: yup, but I don't know the exact things to be done. I have tried all this but I still keep getting caught, and the penalty for this is game-over