# How do I find rich people in Uplink?

Tags: uplink

In my current game of Uplink, my uplink rating went up pretty fast, and I end up rather behind in terms of money. I'm #1 and I can't even afford the HUD_LANView...

I'm also trying to keep my Neuromancer up, so I try to avoid doing "trace a hacker" and "ruin a life" type missions, and other kind of missions are getting rare.

So, I decided that I'd try to hack a bank. Everything went right, and my false account now has a glorious... 8000c, after two thefts. How can I find richer peoples to rob of their belongings? I don't want to steal 4000c by 4000c.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet is to accept all "trace a recent balance transfer" missions, because the transfer is always huge (between 700k and a cool million credits), and after you've traced the receiver, nothing prevents you from robbing them blind.

The only way anyone ever becomes rich is through these missions, anyway. The money starts existing once the mission is generated.

You don't necessarily have to accept the mission to steal the money, but the only alternative is hacking every bank, jotting down all log-in credentials and then manually checking the account, so you really should. These missions themselves are Neuromancer-neutral; however, I believe stealing money lowers your rating.

Comment: I did find such a mission, but the transfer was only 4k... Guess it's not my lucky day... I'll try to find another one.

Comment: @Jupotter That must've been an unauthorized money transfer; *recent* balance transfer missions *always* involve huge sums. Their description usually contains "a sizable amount of money".

Comment: Yeah, it was in fact an unauthorized transfer. I'll try to find a a recent balance transfer then.

Comment: Self-plug for those who want to know how to rob a bank: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/14005/5398

Comment: I just found an account with 1,200,000 credits in it by accessing another account's statement. The account only had 5000 in it, but had just transferred 200000 to another account. I followed it. =3

Comment: The really nice thing about these is you only really need one big job to afford a maxed-out top-of-the-line Gateway.  Then, you can pretty much retire from the grunt work and focus on the story line.  That is, unless you're in the habit of having to nuke your Gateway to avoid being caught.

Comment: I had one today that was 1.3 million. Not that there's any way to spend more than ~500K..

Answer (score 2):

I use the following steps:

1. Pick a random bank.
2. Bounce through InterNIC and *all* public access servers.
3. Hack the bank's admin account.
4. Write down all account numbers.
5. Clear bank and InterNIC logs.
6. Log into bank with each account, checking for high-value transfers.
7. Siphon money from those valuable accounts.

Always clear logs on both ends, and always use monitor and proxy bypass. Also, you should create an account with the bank you are about to steal from. This lets you transfer the money there, so that you only have to clear the logs at one bank, making the stealing process easy.