# Should I avoid connecting to my false account when robbing a bank?

Tags: uplink

When I try to rob a bank, I usually use a false account where I transfer the "generous donation". I create it in the same bank as the bank I rob to avoid IP concerns etc... However, I usually connect directly to it once, trough the finance tab, to check if everything is okay, even tough I create it trough bounces and remove logs.

Sadly, every times I tried to rob a bank, it ended with the dreaded black screen and FBI arrest... Could it be linked to the fact that I connect directly to my false account? if so, how long should I wait before connecting to it, to transfer money to my private account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I got what happens. When I rob the bank, I connect to my dummy account, during the same hacking session as my theft, it is logged into the bank's administrative logs.

So, they can link my dummy account with the theft, and then come back to me trough my "unprotected" login. So, I should avoid using a dummy account on the same bank, or even using one...

Comment: a dummy is fine and important, but don't connect to it during hacking but afterwards. Just delete all logs connecting that dummy account to the hacks (both incoming and outgoing transfers that is!). See [my answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/43671/88)

Answer (score 6):

No, banks investigate large transfers as well as hacks. Your problem is that you're not cleaning up after yourself enough; having a dummy account isn't enough.

It's best to [follow these instructions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10519/how-do-i-make-money-quickly-in-uplink). You shouldn't need a dummy account if you're cleaning up after yourself sufficiently.

Comment: problem is, I do erase the logs of my transfers and my connection, bit I still get traced back.

Comment: you should summarize the other answer in case the link goes stale. Oh wait, it's also on gaming.SE, you should at least clarify that

Comment: Banks have an insanely fast trace and a lot of resources. You need to be very quick to knock over a bank, and you need excellent tools so the bank doesn't simply undelete your logs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to gain access to the log (disable or bypass the proxy or firewall, it's been a while so I don't remember for sure) and delete those (and **only** those) where you put money from the hacked accounts to your dummy account (both withdrawal from the hacked one and deposit on your dummy account, and use the highest level log deleter!). Kill your bump traces (internic is usually the best point) and in a new direct session transfer the money from the dummy account to your main account. Since there's no proof left that this bunch of money was stolen, it's just a legal transfer.